# Why DEFAULT_ONREADY_THRESHOLD is final in java-grpc?

Tags: grpc-java, flow-control

Why is it marked as final [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/d180e6cfa2947921d49ca969261b9f7a997e9e1e/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/internal/AbstractStream.java#L119C29-L119C54) instead of letting the user configure it?

Wouldn't it be more user-friendly for the user to configure this value as needed? If my individual messages are large, I wouldn't want the `onReady()=false` scenario to occur frequently, or if my messages are small, I might want this `onReady=false` scenario to be signaled to me in the early stages of accumulation.

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/5433#issuecomment-472603484